# Unable to access DBFS file with PIP

Tags: databricks

I use a `Shared` Cluster 11.3 LTS in my Databricks Workspace where `Unity Catalog` is enabled.

I have a `requirements.txt` file the folder `FileStore` in `DBFS` which I can see also in the Databricks UI. I also see the file when executing

```
%fs ls FileStore
```

According to [here](https://kb.databricks.com/data/user-does-not-have-permission-select-on-any-file) the Any File permission is required to access a file in `DBFS`. So I was running the following command

```
%sql
GRANT SELECT ON ANY FILE TO `myuser@xxx.at`
```

However, I get a `no such file error` when I try to run

```
%pip install  -r /dbfs/FileStore/requirements.txt
```

as well as

```
%pip install  -r dbfs:/FileStore/requirements.txt
```

When switching to a `No Isolation Shared` Cluster the pip command works. How can I run the command with a `Shared` Cluster.

Comment: Did you mount it as a normal file?

Comment: didn't do any mount

Comment: Pip likely can only read files that are part of your file system not thru an api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UC enabled, don't use /dbfs; please use Volumes or Workspace.

with "No isolation shared"; it is no longer UC.